# Cannot debug a plugin for ReSharper made with SDK

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.1, resharper-sdk

I'm using VisualStudio2010 SP1, ReSharper 6.1.1. and the ReSharper SDK 6.1.0.51. I ban build a new plugin easily with the project wizard, but unfortunately I cannot debug it. No breakpoint will be hit. Even the samples provided with the SDK work, but will not be debuggable. What am I dong wrong?

Comment: Just in case it's relevant, can you tell me what VS plug-ins you are using (if any)?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Following plug-ins are installed: GAX 2010, PowerCommands for VisualStudio2010, Process Template Editor, Productivity Power Tools and WITDesigner. I had the Debugger Canvas installed, but uninstalled it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the problem you're experiencing and have [posted a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288642) that you can subscribe to to keep up to date on its progress. Also, I've been unable to discern immediately the cause of the problem - the plug-in *is* loaded and the breakpoints do not become grayed out.

Comment: I'm pleased that you can replicate the problem - I thought I'm going mad ... did everything like stated in the readme, but it didn't work. Looking forward to the solution.